# add library into android project from GitHub

Tags: android, github, shared-libraries

how to download library from "https://github.com/TangoAgency/material-intro-screen" ?
I want to download library file and add that to my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add this line in your app module gradle file in dependency part:

```
compile 'agency.tango.android:material-intro-screen:0.0.3'
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in your build.gradle file.

```
dependencies {
  compile 'agency.tango.android:material-intro-screen:0.0.3'
}
```

Comment: I add that line to build.gradle but this error is done "{Error:(41, 13) Failed to resolve: agency.tango.android:material-intro-screen:0.0.5
<a href="openFile:C:/Users/hn/AndroidStudioProjects/Chart/app/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>}"

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow these steps (available at the bottom of the github page)

Step 1:

Add gradle dependecy

```
dependencies {
  compile 'agency.tango.android:material-intro-screen:{latest_release}'
}
```

Step 2:

First, your intro activity class needs to extend MaterialIntroActivity:

```
public class IntroActivity extends MaterialIntroActivity
```

Step 3:

Add activity to manifest with defined theme:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".IntroActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Intro" />
```

Step 4:

Add slides:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        addSlide(new SlideFragmentBuilder()
                .backgroundColor(R.color.colorPrimary)
                .buttonsColor(R.color.colorAccent)
                .possiblePermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS})
                .neededPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION})
                .image(agency.tango.materialintroscreen.R.drawable.ic_next)
                .title("title 3")
                .description("Description 3")
                .build(),
                new MessageButtonBehaviour(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        showMessage("We provide solutions to make you love your work");
                    }
                }, "Work with love"));
}
```